# Combining positive and negative lookahead in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-look-ahead

I'm trying to extract tokens that satisfy many conditions out of which, I'm using lookahead to implement the following two conditions:

1. The tokens must be either numeric/alphanumeric (i.e, they must have at least one digit). They can contain few special characters like - `'-','/','\','.','_'` etc.,

I want to match strings like: `165271`, `agya678`, `yah@123`, `kj*12-`

2. The tokens can't have consecutive special characters like: `ajh12-&`

I don't want to match strings like: `ajh12-&`, `671%&i^`

I'm using a positive lookahead for the first condition: `(?=\w*\d\w*)` and a negative lookahead for the second condition: `(?!=[\_\.\:\;\-\\\/\@\+]{2})`

I'm not sure how to combine these two look-ahead conditions.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1** :

I would like to extract complete tokens that are part of a larger string too (i.e., They may be present in middle of the string).

I would like to match all the tokens in the string:
`165271 agya678 yah@123 kj*12-`

and none of the tokens (not even a part of a token) in the string: `ajh12-& 671%&i^`

In order to force the regex to consider the whole string I've also used `\b` in the above regexs : `(?=\b\w*\d\w*\b)` and `(?!=\b[\_\.\:\;\-\\\/\@\+]{2}\b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!=.*[_.:;\-\\\/@+*]{2})(?=[^\d\n]*\d)[\w.:;\-\\\/@+*]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/idiHPX/1)

The negative lookahead `(?=[^\d\n]*\d)` matches any char except a digit or a newline use a negated character class, and then match a digit.

Note that you also have to add `*` and that most characters don't have to be escaped in the character class.

Using contrast, you could also turn the first `.*` into a negated character class to prevent some backtracking

```
^(?!=[^_.:;\-\\\/@+*\n][_.:;\-\\\/@+*]{2})(?=[^\d\n]*\d)[\w.:;\-\\\/@+*]+$
```

---

Edit

Without the anchors, you can use whitespace boundaries to the left `(?<!\S)` and to the right `(?!\S)`

```
(?<!\S)(?!=\S*[_.:;\-\\\/@+*]{2})(?=[^\d\s]*\d)[\w.:;\-\\\/@+*]+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LAjXYm/1)

Comment: @ The fourth bird - I wanted to extract tokens that were part of a larger string also. So I tweaked the regular expression in the demo to this: https://regex101.com/r/nx74gL/1

I have used `\b` in the new regular expression- (?!=\b.*[_.:;\-\\\/@+*]{2}\b)(?=\b[^\d]*\d\b)\b[\w_.:;\-\\\/@+*]+\b.

This is not working. Any idea where things are going wrong?

Comment: @sunehaks Like this `/(?<!\S)(?!=\S*[_.:;\-\\\/@+*]{2})(?=[^\d\s]*\d)[\w_.:;\-\\\/@+*]+(?!\S)/gm` See 
 https://regex101.com/r/dPBPIr/1

Comment: @sunehaks Do you also want to match spaces in your tokens?

Comment: I have few other rules for matching. I mainly needed help with the lookaheads.

Comment: @sunehaks This is a slighyly shorted pattern with less backtracking `\b(?!.*[\W_]{2})(?=[^\d\n]*\d).*\b` see https://regex101.com/r/qdUjd7/1

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I appreciate your efforts. I had few doubts here- doesn't `(?!.*[\W_]{2})` mean- not to match `token ending with 2 consecutive special characters at the end`?In practice, there may be two or more consecutive special characters in any place in the token. I tried it on another token `thy5681u` that is supposed to be extracted: https://regex101.com/r/qdUjd7/2. The same token seems to match in one place and not match in another place. This seems strange and is one of the problems I'm facing with the final regular expression as well. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @sunehaks You do not match the first one because `\W` also matches a newline. So the negative lookahead `(?!.*[\W_]{2})` means assert not 2 non word chars. After the first occurrence of `thy5681u` that is false because there are 2 newlines after it. This is a negated version excluding the newlines. `\b(?!.*[^\wA-Za-z0-9\r\n]{2})(?=[^\d\n]*\d).*\b` See  https://regex101.com/r/tVS8Fl/1

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple look ahead assertions to only capture strings that

1. `(?!.*(?:\W|_){2,}.*)` - doesn't have consecutive special characters and
2. `(?=.*\d.*)` - has at least 1 digit

```
^(?!.*(?:\W|_){2,}.*)(?=.*\d.*).*$
```

Comment: May need to be careful with `\W` since it doesn't include `_` which is in the list of non-repeatable. This regex matches `'___a1___'` for example.

Comment: @Niel Godfrey Ponciano - I removed the ^ and $ as I wanted to extract tokens that were part of a larger string too and added \b at the beginning and the end of both the lookaheads to meet my needs. It is working great! Thanks!